# How to close previously opened screen in nested navigator, and reopen it again without changes

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have following navigators structure

- Tab navigator

  - Tab1

    - StackNavigator

      - ScreenA
      - ScreenB
  - Tab2

    - StackNavigator

      - ScreenC
      - ScreenD
  - Tab3

    - StackNavigator

      - ScreenE
      - ScreenF

On screen E there is a form, and depending on route params passed to this screen, certain inputs are shown or hidden.

When i go to ScreenA, and from this screen navigate to ScreenE with param x, then by clicking a tab go to screen C, and navigate to ScreenE with param y, i want ScreenE to be closed and reopened again with cleared form based on param y. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

In my case I write a workaround solution which reset the destination route with new params. however, depends on your logic maybe you could just reinitialize the states of screen E

```js
//reset screen that is going to navigate to (screen is existed in stack)
//"@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.9",
export function navigateReset(navigation, screenName, newParams) {
  navigation.dispatch(state => {
    // find target route
    const routes = [...state.routes];
    const index = routes.findIndex(r => r.name === screenName);
    if (index > -1) {
      // remove target route and after routes
      routes.splice(index);

      return CommonActions.reset({
        ...state,
        routes: [
          ...routes,
          {
            ...state.routes[index],
            key: state.routes[index].key + '1',
            params: newParams,
          },
        ],
        index: routes.length,
      });
    } else {
      // if not found just navigate
      return CommonActions.navigate({name: screenName, params: newParams});
    }
  });
}
```